# How to bind an object to an option value in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to put an object as a value with `ngValue` but I only get one value

Here is what I tried:

```html
<select class="friend-input" (change)="selectFriend($event.target.value)">
  <option disabled selected>Select a friend...</option>
  <option
    *ngFor="let friend of friends"
    [ngValue]="friend"
  >
    {{ friend.userName }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Component:

```
export interface Friends {
  userUid: string;
  userName: string;
}

friends: Friends[];

selectFriend(friend) {
  console.log(friend);
}
```

The `console.log` returns only the `friend.userName` and not the other values in the object

and If I only do `[value]="friend"` I get `[object Object]`

How can I bind an object to a value in Angular?

Comment: use `[(ngModel)]`, probably the first thing you should learn about angular ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[(ngModel)]="selectedFriend"` and `(ngModelChange)="selectFriend($event)"`

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<select class="friend-input" (ngModelChange)="selectFriend($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedFriend">
  <option disabled selected>Select a friend...</option>
  <option
    *ngFor="let friend of friends"
    [ngValue]="friend"
  >
    {{ friend.userName }}
  </option>
</select>
```

TS:

```
  selectFriend(friend:Friends) {
    console.log(friend);
  }
```

See [Stackbiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztgbyw)

Comment: I get a console.log of type Event but not type Friend, how can I make it return an object of Friend?

Comment: Modified the answer. Add `selectFriend(friend:Friends)`